# How to Increase socket memory allocation in Linux kernel

Tags: sockets, memory, linux-kernel, datagram

I'm implementing a custom transport layer datagram protocol in the Linux kernel. I've implement send and receive Queues for in-order delivery in lossy environments.

I noticed that with my current implementation, My socket runs out of memory with only 16 socket buffers with BUFSIZ payload in the queue. So I need to increase the value of memory allocated to my socket.

I figured that changing the values of `sk->sk_sendbuf` and `sk->sk_rcvbuf` should do the job. What is the correct way to do this?

P.S.- I haven't implemented the sysctl interface for this protocol yet, so can't use that for memory management.

Thanks.

Comment: What's taking up all memory? If it's data, isn't fragmentation the way to deal with that?

Comment: I'm trying to preserve message boundaries, so fragmentation is not an option. What's taking up the memory is the allocation of socket buffers and when there are unacked buffers in the queue (16 to be precise), I can't allocate any more buffers with the `sock_alloc` function in the kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I need not define the sysctl interface manually for my protocol. I just used the following sysctl command on my test machine to increase the amount of memory allocated to each socket

```
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=<new_value>
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=<new_value>
```

To select the `new_value`, I first checked the existing value of these parameters with

```
sysctl -n net.core.wmem_default
sysctl -n net.core.wmem_max
```

Note that the actual memory assigned to the socket will be twice the `new_value`, that's just how the implementation is in the kernel.